Laravel eloquent, how to query in relationtionship table with Or Where
I have a Game model, with relations to Location model.
I wanna search in the game's name field, as well as the game's location's name field. And the game's start time must be greater than today's date.
$games = Game::with('user', 'location')
    ->when($this->searchterm !== '', fn(Builder $query)
        => $query->where('name', 'like', '%'. $this->searchterm .'%')->orWhere('location.name', 'like', '%'. $this->searchterm .'%')
    )
    ->orderBy('start_time', 'ASC')
    ->whereDate('end_time', '>', Carbon::now())
    ->paginate(100);

This doesn't work. It throws the following error:
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'location.name' in 'where clause'
How can I fix this problem?

You need to use whereHas() (or, in your case, ->orWhereHas()) to query a Relationship, or you need to manually join the tables. Using dot-notation location.name to attempt to query it doesn't work like that unfortunately.

When Eloquent loads relationships (In your case, loading the Game's user and location relationships via with('user', 'location')), it does not use joins on the main query, meaning you cannot simply use where/orWhere like what you've tried.
Instead, you need to specifically use Eloquent methods to query the relationship's existence
$games = Game::query()
    ->with('user', 'location')
    ->when(
        $this->searchterm !== '',
        fn (Builder $query) => $query
            ->where(function (Builder $sql) {
                $sql->where('name', 'like', "%{$this->searchterm}%")
                    ->orWhereRelation('location', 'name', 'like', "%{$this->searchterm}%");
            })
    )
    ->orderBy('start_time', 'ASC')
    ->whereDate('end_time', '>', Carbon::now())
    ->paginate(100);


https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/queries#logical-grouping (where(function (...) {...}))
https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence (whereHas/orWhereHas)
https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/eloquent-relationships#inline-relationship-existence-queries (whereRelation/orWhereRelation)


I tried this, but the result is incorrect, as it also returned games which have already ended.. "whereDate('end_time', '>', Carbon::now())" should made it only return games which are still active and not already ended.

Before adding orWhereRelation, the query returns games which are still active (not already ended), which is correct. After adding orWhereRelation, the query then also returns games which have already ended, this is not what I want. How can we amend this problem?

Ah, I completely missed the whereDate use when I was copying the code. That happens because the WHERE clauses are not grouped. I'll edit my answer.

Oh yes, now it works well! Thank you very much. By the way, do you know why I get -3 for my question?

You're welcome. And I can't give you a good reason since I'm no psychic. A bit of bad luck? Maybe users that were in a bad mood happened to dislike your question. Maybe users who are familiar with the framework thought it was too basic considering the available documentation. Maybe users thought the way you redacted the question was unclear. In any case your question right now is at (+1/-4) so if you care about reputation you still have a net gain.
